# How to prepare a parsable json array of object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var cdrType = $('.switchSelect').val();
console.log(cdrDisplayFields);//[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
var a = '{"cdrColumnFields":'+cdrDisplayFields[0]+'}';
console.log(a); //{"cdrColumnFields":[object Object]}
console.log(cdrDisplayFields[0]); //Object {cdrName: "EQUIPMENTID", type: "date", index: 0}
console.log($.parseJSON(a)); //VM2901:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 20
```

How to prepare a valid json array of objects if i have an array of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't append an object to a string. You need to `JSON.stringify()` the `cdrDisplayFields[0]` object:

```
var a = '{"cdrColumnFields":' + JSON.stringify(cdrDisplayFields[0]) + '}';
```

Note that a *much* better alternative would be to create an object yourself and then stringify it all together, like this:

```
var a = JSON.stringify({ cdrColumnFields: cdrDisplayFields[0] });
```

Also note that turning the above object in to JSON is redundant if all you're going to do is `$.parseJSON` it back to an object again.

Comment: Thankyou, it's really helped me to resolve the issue.

//cdrDisplayFields is an array of objects
var b = JSON.stringify({cdrColumnFields: cdrDisplayFields});
console.log(b);